# Unable to display google maps in a dojo layout

Tags: google-maps, layout, dojo

I am a real newbie in programming and now I have to combine Google Maps and Dojo. Both alone are fine but when I try to implement a Google Map into a Dojo content pane which is embedded in a border-container it simply does not work. I think there is a problem with the naming of the divs but perhaps there is something else to take care of?

Could someone post the simplest possible solution?

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure it out myself.

Here is the answer:
Actually I was going to use ArcGIS Server Javascript extension for GoogleMaps and Dojo together. Thus we have to sure that all references to APIs are made correctly.

I think it is wise to use the Dojo components directly from the ArcGIS Server-API pages instead of loading from the DOJO network. This should guarantee the compatability between all components.

```
<!--Load Google Maps API -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA22G6YWIfghc6CfXo3jGlQBQIhNZriPAS64ZF0ztgQFnJUtUvlhSuBly8ueb8pLmxY8qzKANsSXJhUA" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--load arcgis-javascript for googlemaps api -->
<script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/gmaps/?v=1.4" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<!--load arcgis js api -->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=1.4"></script>

<!--load the required Dojo components -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojox.data.XmlStore");
  dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");

  <!--This loads the esri specific geoprocessing tool -->
  dojo.require("esri.tasks.gp");  

  <!-- defining variables -->
  var gmap = null;
  var dynMapOv = null;
</script>
```

Then, after the initializing function is set up...

```
 function initialize() {
  //Load Google Maps
  gmap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("gmap"));
  var centerat = new GLatLng(-1, 23.7);
  gmap.setCenter(centerat, 3); ...
```

... one has to ensure load the function with

```
dojo.addOnLoad(initialize);
```

Furthermore, it is important to put a reference to the the dojo-theme in the body tag of the HTML code.

```
  <body  class="soria"  onunload="GUnload();">
```

I hope this very basic stuff helps someone who is not sure about how to combine AGS+GoogleMaps+Dojo.